# Construct a set of local rules in plane such that all permitted tilings are non periodic.(there exists at least one tiling)

Tags: combinatorics, tiling

This is the problem given to me on a practice.

I imagine the problem is understandable but if there is anything unexplained, please tell me.

I have tried various things to solve this problem but all of them lead to a dead-end, and so far I don't think I have made any good progress to share.

Here are some definitions I think would be helpful to write.

"local rules: a set of $n.n$ squares which are forbidden in the tiling ($n$ is not a constant and can be any positive integer greater than $1$)",

"non periodic : means there is not a non_zero vector such that after adding the tiling to that vector we reach the same tiling",and the plane we are tiling the plane using $1.1$ black or white squares

Comment: Forbid $1\times 1$ white and forbid $1\times 1$ black. Then "all" permitted tilings are non-periodic

Comment: that is quite a nice bug to mention. i will correct it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a set of aperiodic [Wang tiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wang_tile) as a starting point.

Wang tiles are normally depicted with colours, but you can choose to represent each tile by almost any n by n pattern of black and white cells, as long as they are unique enough.

Then enumerate all ways that you are allowed to make a patch of four Wang tiles which form a 2n by 2n square of black and white cells. List all n by n sub-squares of these allowed patches, giving you all the posssible n by n patterns that you will allow in the tiling as a whole. Then disallow all other n by n patterns.

This shows it can be done, though the list of local rules will be very long.

Comment: thanks! i was thinking about using the wang tiles but couldn't do so.

Comment: @Mr.C My answer is a bit vague on the size of n. It has to be large enough, and the patterns you choose for the tiles have to be unique enough that your list of allowed n by n patterns do not allow you to do any tiling other than the one dictated by the original Wang tiles. I suspect you can get it down to 4x4, but 3x3 might be pushing it.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis $4\times 4$ is *definitely* possible: Rotate the wang pattern by 45° an drepresent each coloured square by $3\times 3$, first row `wbb` as "sync", second and third row both encode the four colour with odd parity (i.e., `bww`, `wbw`, `wwb`and `bbb`). Then each $4\times 4$ has two consecutive identical rows in a unique way. The row(s) below or above must be sync rows, so we recognize where top left corners are. suitable overlaps will exhibit all four colours. done. -- That looks like (slightly less than) $16\cdot 11$ allowed $4\times 4$ patterns to me.

Answer (score 1):

Allow only "pixelated sections" of Penrose tilings.

[image]

To elaborate: Let us first assign integer coordinates to all parallelogram vertices in the above image:

- Assign $(0,0)$ to the centre (where five "thick" parallelograms meet)
- Assign $(-3,0)$ to its left neighbour and from there assign $(-1,-2)$, $(2,-1)$, $(2,1)$, $(-1,2)$ to its other four neighbours counter-clockwise.
- From this, you can extend assigning integer coordinates to parallelogram vertices by using the parallelogram rule, i.e., that we demand
  $ x_2-x_1=x_3-x_4$ and $y_2-y_1=y_3-y_4$ for a parallelogram with vertices $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_4,y_4)$.

Now turn this into a tiling of the square latice by black/white tiles, namely make the tile at $(x,y)$ black iff $(x,y)$ is one of the infinitely many vertices labelled above.
This is an aperiodic tiling of the square lattice.

Now *forbid* all $6\times6$ patterns that do *not* appera in this aperiodic tiling.
(Or put differently: Allow only such $6\times 6$ patterns that do occur).
It requires checking, but it seems quite clear that all lattice tilings that use only allowed patterns must correspond to a Penrose tiling and therefore are aperiodic.

Comment: but we are soppused to use $1.1$ squares of black and white colour. not polygons :(

Comment: @Mr.C The image was only for an overall impression. Simply put, turn the image into black and white and consider all squares of size, I don't know, $10\times 10$ pixels? At least these patches need not be bigger than needed to cover a single thick or thin parallelogram in each of its five orientations. Now forbid any $10\times 10$(?) pattern that does not occur in the Penrose tiling.

Comment: maybe i did not made my self clear. but we are tiling a greed. and again maybe i am wrong but i see no way to turn the shape you drew to a tiling of the infinite greed.

Comment: @Mr.C He explained very clearly how to turn this into a tiling of an infinite grid; "Now turn this into a tiling of the square lattice by black/white tiles, namely make the tile at (x,y) black iff [if and only if] (x,y) is one of the infinitely many vertices labelled above."

Comment: sorry ... but i dont understand how that happens :( ... jaap's solution was more understandable for me

Comment: @Mr.C Well, essentially the solutions are the same :) Wang tiles have the advantage of fitting even easier into the square latice constraint